# Varnish Backend Health Polling

Tags: varnish

we use varnish 3.02  with cache server, and have 6 and more servers as backends with different weight ,so round-robin may not for us,

we use  random director  with  below  health check, but it seems not working

```
probe apachehealthcheck {
        .url = "/test/test.php";
        .interval = 3s;
        .timeout = 3 s;
        .window = 5;
        .threshold = 3;
        .initial = 3;
        .expected_response = 200; }


 backend passport backend passport1 {
        .host = "192.168.2.192";
        .port = "80";
        .connect_timeout = 10s;
        .first_byte_timeout = 50s;
        .between_bytes_timeout = 30s;
        .probe = apachehealthcheck; }


director passport_cluster random {
        {.backend = flpassport1;.weight = 1;}
        {.backend = flpassport2;.weight = 2;}   
                ...    }
```

i saw the lines below at  https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling

> The random director will not consider backends which are unhealthy
>   part of the pool.

does it mean when i am useing random director in varnish, when some backends broken,  it still  forward the request to ?

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems your backend config-part is in error.
Split up or shorten the part "backend passport backend passport1". It's double.